# Typing effect to text in JTextArea

Tags: java, swing, delay, jtextarea

I am making a program that has a JTextArea. I am using the **append()** method to add text to it. I want the text to be like someone is typing in the JTextArea, i.e. it should type one character, then wait for 400 milliseconds, the the next character, then again wait, and so on.
This is my code:

```
public void type(String s)
{
    char[] ch = s.toCharArray();
    for(int i = 0; i < ch.length; i++)
    {
        // ta is the JTextArea
        ta.append(ch[i]+"");
        try{new Robot().delay(400);}catch(Exception e){}
    }
}
```

But this is not working. It waits for some seconds, without displaying anything, and then displays the whole text at once. Please suggest.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use `javax.swing.Timer` instead. Keep reference to the `JTextArea` instance and char index. On each `actionPerformed()` call append current char to the `JTextArea`. When the char index equals to the char array length stop the Timer

Comment: Explain with an example,so that the beginers can understand

Answer (score 0):

Try using this, replace your for loop by this while:

```
int i=0;
while(i<s.length())
    {
        // ta is the JTextArea
        ta.append(s.charAt(i));

    try 
    {
        Thread.sleep(400);                
    } catch(InterruptedException ex) {
        Thread.currentThread().interrupt();
    }
     i++;
}
```

**Edit:**

I just edited it to avoid thread problem:

```
int i=0;
while(i<s.length())
    {
        // ta is the JTextArea
        ta.append(s.charAt(i));

    try {
    TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS.sleep(400);
    } catch (InterruptedException e) {
    // TODO Auto-generated catch block
    e.printStackTrace();
    }
     i++;
}
```

Comment: Yes infact I just edited it , I missed to remove the for loop line.But now it works.

Comment: No, it does not work. `JTextArea#append` should be called on the EDT, so your `Thread.sleep` call would block the EDT and ensures that the repaint can't take place

Answer (score -2):

```
public void type(final String s)
{   
    new Thread(){     
      public void run(){
         for(int i = 0; i < s.length(); i++)
          {
            // ta is the JTextArea
            ta.append(""+s.charAt(i));
            try{Thread.sleep(400);}catch(Exception e){}
          }
      }
   }.start();
}
```

check above code will work fine.

Comment: `Thread.sleep` on the Event Dispatch Thread is never a good solution as it blocks the UI

Comment: I have updated the code. Now it will not block the UI.